# What is the real name for a "unit-basis" of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

What is the real name for a "unit-basis" of a ring?

Let $R''$ be the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$. I am interested in the prime ideal $(x, y)$ and in the construction (called localization, I think) that knocks out some of the other ideals in $R''$ by constructing a ring of fractions whose denominators are taken from $R'' \setminus (x, y)$. $(x, y)$ is not a principal ideal, so I figured this construction would give me back an interesting ring.

Let $S$ be the complement of the prime ideal $(x, y)$. Since $(x, y)$ is a prime ideal, it follows that $S$ is multiplicatively closed.

Let $R$ be $R''/S$, the ring of fractions with numerators in $R''$ and denominators in $S$.

I was trying to come up with a normal form for elements of $R''/S$ when I stumbled across the following.

Let $G$ be the group of units of $R$, i.e. fractions of the form $\frac{p(x, y)}{q(x, y)}$ that aren't equivalent to zero where $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ are both in $S$.

Elements of $R$ can be represented as finite sums of the form $\sum_{ij}g_{ij}x^i y^j$ where $g_{ij}$ is a coefficient taking a value in $G$.

As proof, an element of $R$ has the form $\frac{p(x, y)}{q(x, y)}$ where $q(x, y)$ is in $S$. $p(x, y)$ is a finite sum of monomials, i.e. elements of the form $kx^my^n$ where $k$ is a nonzero complex number.

So we have $\frac{\sum_i k_i x^{m_i} y^{n_i}}{q(x, y)}$ which is $\sum_i \frac{k_i x^{m_i} y^{n_i} }{q(x, y)}$ which is equal to $\sum_i \frac{k_i}{q(x, y)} x^{m_i} y^{n_i} $ which is a sum of elements of the form $ux^m y^n$ where $u$ is a unit in $R$.

This means that our ring $R$ has a "unit-basis" $B = \{x^0y^0, x^0y^1, x^1y^0, x^0y^2, x^1y^1, x^2y^0, \cdots\}$ in the sense that any element of $R$ can be represented as a finite linear combination of elements of $B$ with coefficients taken from $G$.

That's kind of interesting.

Another ring, $\mathbb{Z}$ has a "unit-basis" of $\{1\}$. Any integer can be represented as a finite sum of $\pm 1$.

Any field also has $\{1\}$ as a "unit-basis" because every element besides zero is a unit, and zero is the sum of $1$ and $-1$.

$\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has $\{x^0, x^1, \cdots\}$ as a "unit-basis".

"Unit-bases" aren't unique, but they seem like a mildly interesting concept for showing how the field of units interacts with the rest of the ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a unital commutative ring and $B$ be the smallest subring containing $A^\times$, which is also the additive subgroup generated by $A^\times$.

Then $A$ is a $B$-module and what you are describing is a subset $E\subset A$ such that $E$ generates $A$ as a $B$-module.

That is every element of $A$ is a finite sum of the form $\sum_{j=1}^J b_j e_j$ with $b_j\in B,e_j\in E$,
and $b_j$ is itself a finite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{I_j} u_{ij}$ of units.